# PHP file upload with multiple post values

Tags: php, html, post, file-upload

I'm having a form that the user can fill in like this:

```
<form id="regForm" action="" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
   <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control">
   <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control">
   <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control">
   <input type="file" name="callflowfile" class="form-control"> // the file
   <input type="submit" name="formpost" class="form-control">
</form>
```

But when I post this form including the file, the file doesn't get uploaded and added to the DB.
This is my `PHP` code:

```
if(isset($_POST['formpost'])){

  // insert name- address - city - county to DB

  // insert callflowfile to directory
  // If The array exists, add callflowfile
    if ($_FILES["callflowfile"]["name"])
    {

        //Count number of files in array, loop through each file
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['callflowfile']['name']); $i++) 
        {

            // If the file in array exists
            if ($_FILES["callflowfile"]["name"][$i])
            {

                // If the file isnt 0 bytes
                if ($_FILES["callflowfile"]["error"][$i] > 0) 
                {}
                else 
                {

                    //move the file 

                    // first get the original name of the uploaded file
                    $filename = $_FILES["callflowfile"]["name"][$i];

                    // now rename the original file into a random name
                    // get the file extension first
                    $ext = substr(strrchr($filename, "."), 1);

                    // then generate the random file name
                    $randomName = md5(rand() * time());
                    $filePath = "documents/" . $randomName . '.' . $ext;

                    // move the file and rename it 
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["callflowfile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filePath)){
                        // Add uploaded file row to database    
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The file isn't uploaded while the other form values are saved correctly.
I get the following error:

> Undefined index: callflowfile in //directory

Does anyone know how to upload a file next to other form post values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form so that it allows file(s) to be posted/uploaded :

```
<form id="regForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And you need to adjust file processing loop conditionals, change it like this :

```
if (isset($_POST['formpost'])) {

    // insert name- address - city - county to DB

    // insert callflowfile to directory
    // If The array exists, add callflowfile
    if ($_FILES["callflowfile"]["tmp_name"]) {

        //Count number of files in array, loop through each file
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['callflowfile']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
...
```

Comment: Then It gives me this error: `Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable` because of the for loop

Answer (score 0):

replace your form tag by this

```
     <form id="regForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And after update kindly do var_dump($_POST,$_FILES) at the first line of your php file you will get the all post fields within $_POST variable and Information of file will get in $_FILES